# Passing content of a div to Facebook share

Tags: javascript, html

I've a javascript quiz function and I got the following code to share some custom text and a link to Facebook.

```
function share(score){
     var desc=encodeURIComponent("Hey, I scored "+score+" in a quiz");
    window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.yoursite.com&description="+desc);
}
```

The result of the quiz is in a div and I want to share that div content along with the custom text above.

Here's the div

```
<div id="totalPoints">some score</div>
```

So what I want to do is, get the content of that div "totalPoints" and add it to the custom text so that It'll  look like "Hey, I scored some score in a quiz" when I share it to Facebook. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

function share(score){

var scored = document.getElementById('totalPoints').innerHTML;

var desc=encodeURIComponent("Hey, I scored "+ scored +" in a quiz"); window.open("https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=www.yoursite.com&description="+desc); }

Comment: Thanks but getting this - "Hey, I scored undefined in a quiz"

Comment: Did you use value or values? I edited my answer to value instead of values

Comment: I used value not values

Comment: Got it. I've to use innerHTML instead of value. Thanks for the help

Comment: Btw, is there any way to change the resulting text a little? What I mean is this. I don't want the entire div text to be passed to facebook. Only the number. For example, if the div text is this "Your score is 4 and you attended 6 questions" , I want to pass that "4" only. Is it possible?

Comment: We've to use Regular Expression. Solution to get '4' is : var score = document.getElementById('totalPoints').innerHTML;var scored = score.match(/(\d+)*[0-9](\d+)*/g); console.log(scored[0]);